# Find the volume of the solid within the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=9$, outside the cone $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, and above the $xy$-plane.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Find the volume of the solid within the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=9$, outside the cone $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, and above the $xy$-plane.

Using Cylindrical coordinates,
 $r^2+z^2=9$ and $z=r$. Intersection is $x^2+y^2=\frac{9}{2}$

\begin{align}
V=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{\frac{3}{\sqrt 2}}^{3}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{9-r^2}}r\:dz\:dr\:d\theta+\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\frac{3}{\sqrt2}}\int_0^r r\:dz\:dr\:d\theta
\end{align}
Again Using Spherical coordinates,
I can't figure out $\phi$ and $\rho$. I just need those limit anyone can skip evaluation. And is my first approach correct$?$ Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advances.

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{9/2}$ is not $3/2$

Comment: @Empy2 it's a typo. thanks for mentioning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the following substitutions for spherical coordinates:
$$z = \rho \cos(\phi)$$
$$x = \rho \sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)$$
$$y = \rho \sin(\phi)\sin(\theta)$$
\begin{align}
\rho \cos(\phi)&=\sqrt{\rho^2 \sin^2(\phi)\cos^2(\theta)+\rho^2 \sin^2(\phi)\sin^2(\theta)}\\
&=\sqrt{\rho^2\sin^2(\phi)}\\
\phi&=\frac{\pi}{4}
\end{align}
Above the $xy$-plane hence $\phi\leq \frac{\pi}{2}\implies \frac{\pi}{4}\leq\phi\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_0^{3}\rho^2 \sin(\phi) d\rho d\phi d\theta$$You can think the volume is whole upper hemisphere except the cone that's why $0\leq \theta\leq 2\pi$ and $0\leq \rho\leq 3$

Comment: Your last comment give me intuition of $\rho$ and $\phi$ @emonHR thanks. Did I am correct in Cylindrical coordinate$?$